# How to sanitise input before using system command in C

Tags: c, security, system, printf

This is my code in C:

```
snprintf(buffer, 1023, "ls -%s", argv[1]);
system(buffer);
```

How can I sanitize the buffer, so that no one can run a malicious command apart from what's given?

Comment: Is using `execv` an option?

Comment: no , i need to wait for it to finish.. :(

Comment: I meant in conjunction with `fork`. The POSIX API for process creation is a bit cumbersome, but can make secure coding much easier.

Comment: can you please provide some sample.. i am beginner in c..

Comment: After a rapid search on google, I just found this link: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ENV03-C.+Sanitize+the+environment+when+invoking+external+programs maybe it could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a very big topic that can't possibly be covered in a SO question.  Fortunately there is [a phenomenal book out there about Secure Coding in C and C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321822137).  That book was used as a "textbook" for my company's secure coding class, and it's very good.

There are dozens of different ways to sanitize input, and the best one to choose depends almost entirely on where the input comes from, and how it will be used.  Where you're passing it to system(), you need to research in depth and you should really have a Security Engineer review your design.  The reason is that there could be exploitable vulnerabilities in the `ls` binary that could be triggered using only standard characters, or there could be buffer overflow vulnerabilities that you're not aware of, etc.

Speaking specifically to your scenario, and only looking for the simplest attacks, if you *recursively* remove all `;` `&&` `||` `$` `(` `)`, you defeat most of the attacks that I can think of easily.  Note that this does nothing though to prevent an exploitation of the binary to which you're passing the input to as an arg (in this case, `ls`), rather it only protects against common shell characters that take on special meaning and allow the executing of arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, this is impossible. The C standard does not make any claim regarding who is interpreting the command passed through `system`. If you write an escape function for the borne shell, for example, that may be completely useless on a Windows system or on a system using a different command shell.